# Отправка данных с JavaScript на php

Tags: php, javascript

Как отправить данные с Javascript на php и получить ответ от php в переменную.
Конкретнее:

1. Js отправляет информацию о выбранном пользователем логином на php
2. Php обрабатывает ее и если логин занят отправляет обратно на js `false`, а если нет - `true`
3. Js заносит ответ в переменную

Вот как я пытался реализовать:

Js:

```
                            var loginr;
                            $$a({
                                type: 'post',
                                url: "check.php",
                                data: {"login":login},
                                response: "text",
                                succes:function (){
                                    loginr = $$("result");
                                }
                            });
                            if(loginr == true){
                                var div = document.querySelector("#login");
                                div.className = "true";
                                div.innerHTML = "✓Логин не занят";
                                alogin = null;
                                alogin = true;
                            }
                            if(loginr == false){
                                var div = document.querySelector("#login");
                                div.className = "false";
                                div.innerHTML = "Логин занят!";
                                alogin = null;
                                alogin = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    }
                });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
if(isset($_POST["login"]){
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    if($login == ''){
        unset($login);
    }
    $login = stripslashes($login);
    $login = htmlspecialchars($login);
    $login = trim($login);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE login='$login'", $db);
    $myrow = mysql_fecth_array($result);
    if(!empty($myrow['id'])){
        echo 'false';
    }else{
        echo 'true';
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: С чем конкретно возникли проблемы? Проверьте и приведите в порядок js

Comment: Проблема возникла с js, он не работает. А вообще: все это работать должно?

Comment: Разбирайтесь с ajax. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/